# Is there an official Otaku day?

Tags: culture

I've stumbled upon many posts on G+ and FB ([example](https://plus.google.com/113953983820887855729/posts/ZtCQePzcgFV)) that state that December 15th is some sort of official Otaku Day.
I've also found [this page](http://denyroseclamp.deviantart.com/journal/December-15-Otaku-s-day-343046900) which is from 2012, which means this was celebrated, at least, in 2012 too.
However, I found no reliable pages that say that this is a thing, much like the person who posted the first post on [this forum](http://forum.icotaku.com/sujet/1147.html).

I found [this ANN article](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/press-release/2013-08-06/3rd-annual-international-otaku-day) that puts this year's Otaku Day on August 17th ([2012's was on the 18th](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/press-release/2012-08-15/2nd-annual-international-otaku-day)). Furthermore, the second link provided there links to a [Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/InternationalOtakuDay), in which it is stated that this event takes place on the third Saturday of August every year.

The event announced on the first paragraph is, apparently, called "World Otaku Day". The one announced on the second is the "(Annual) International Otaku Day". However, I find no reference of any of these two, nor of any "official" Otaku day on Wikipedia.

So, is there a day that is really (official, or something of the sort) regarded as Otaku Day? Are there any more reliable sources that have a fixed date for this event?
Or are these two events relatively official and both recognised as two different Otaku days?

Comment: Every day is otaku day.

Comment: @Eric +1, and yeah Jnat is tomorrow :D

Comment: Nearly 3k Views in 22 hours. Not bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've been searching for official answers, as you said, this is probably new, started on 2012 (or at most, 2011). All what I could find are some personal posts.

I have searched Google for similar images of the one below (the one below is used to advertise for OtakuDay):

[image: otaku day]

And so, I found the original drawing [here](http://delishbooru.com/post/show/6616/coffee-kizoku-shibuya_rin-the_idolm-ster-the_idolm) with title "coffee-kizoku-shibuya_rin-the_idolm-ster-the_idolm", which is a fan-art of an anime/manga character, but it has nothing to do with the OtakuDay.

I've searched twitter for [#OtakuDay](https://twitter.com/search?q=#OtakuDay&src=hash), there is really nothing official even on that hash tag, all I found is personal posts again (and it is probably started on 2011).

So far, the only official (non-personal) thing is actually what you posted from the AnimeNewsNetwork.com:

[2nd Annual International Otaku Day](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/press-release/2012-08-15/2nd-annual-international-otaku-day) = 3rd Saturday of August = "August 18, 2012"

[3rd Annual International Otaku Day](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/press-release/2013-08-06/3rd-annual-international-otaku-day) = 3rd Saturday of August = "August 17, 2013"

So, the **1st Annual International Otaku Day** = 3rd Saturday of August = "August 20, 2011"

As for the **Dec 15** it's made up in **2010** and it has been spreading since then. I finally could find the source, the oldest and very first one is this: [**here**](http://kagene.tumblr.com/post/13628693735/all-otakus-listen-up) in tumblr posted on **14th Jul 2010**

**EDIT:**

So, the **1st Annual International Otaku Day - 3rd Saturday of August = "August 20, 2011"** is by the ANN. And the **December 15th is World Day of Otaku** is made by anime/manga fans.